# Can the allowed cities for the Careers ad be specified?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs, advertising

I see many Careers ads in Stack Overflow  right sidebar. However, most of them are in a city that I would never move to (although it is relatively close to me). Is there any way to exclude job offers in certain cities? Or better, only specify the cities I *am* interested in? If not, could this, or an option to "dismiss" job offers be added?

Comment: I'd love to have "relatively close" ones. 2 of the 4 showing for me now are over 250 miles away (and there are plenty of closer jobs in the system when I search).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but not at the moment. BUT we are working on a huge project to fix things like that. Hopefully in the next couple of months.

**EDIT** Just to clarify, ad targeting will get a lot better, but there may or may not be a way for you to go in and affect ad targeting yourself. We're still trying to work everything out but we will certainly add this to the user request bucket.

Comment: So  [meta-tag:status-planned] or [meta-tag:status-deferred]?